# How can I remove spacing between QGridLayout and page? PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

```
class StartPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        # Start Page Preferences
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.setObjectName("body")
        self.setStyleSheet(cssLoader("styles.css"))
        self.move(150, 150)

        # Customizing Grid Layout
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(15):
                a = QWidget()
                a.setStyleSheet("background-color : blue;border : 1px solid black")
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(a, i, j, 1, 1)
```

When I run this GUI there is a margin between page and QGridLayout. here is image of problem(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPx7b.png)

This is my first try with QGridLayout so if it's so easy welcome me.

Comment: Add this line `self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`. This isn't specific to gridlayouts. It works for all layouts.